# DivideByZeroException is only thrown in Mono builds, not in IL2CPP. Why?

Tags: unity, exceptions, mono, il2cpp

I'm working on exception handling and I usually test it with causing a `DivideByZeroException`.

But this time **it's not thrown**. (While throwing a `System.Exception` works just like usual).

So I've created an **empty project** with only this script:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        Debug.Log("L");
        var x = 0;
        var y = 1 / x;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        Debug.Log("P");
        throw new System.Exception("test");
    }
}
```

And with the empty project the `DivideByZeroException` **is thrown**, so I had a look on the project configurations.

Turns out the new project's **Scripting Backend is Mono**.

Once I changed it from Mono to **IL2CPP**, the `DivideByZeroException` **is not thrown** in this project as well.

[image]

I experimented with changing the **API Compability Level**, but they **behave the same**.

[image]

So last time I debugged exception handling, I was on Mono and then I changed it ... I guess to make it faster or something.

My question is: **why is this the case?**

Comment: Wild guess: both variables get optimized out because they are not used

Comment: @user253751 Yes, you are probably right. I added a line: gameObject.name = y.ToString() so it's now used. Now it crashes when I press L. So yes, probably it was removed due to not being used. But then my followup question is: Why doesn't it just throw an exception? Instead of crashing alltogether? The System.Exception throwing hotkey still works just as it should: I press the key -> dev console appears with exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user253751 pointed it out: **both variables get optimized out** because they are **not used**.

Yes, most likely that's the case. I added a line:

`gameObject.name = y.ToString()`

Now it **crashes** when I press L.

So yes, probably it was removed due to not being used.

It's still interesting **why does it crash instead of just throwing an exception.**

Comment: "Why does it crash instead of just throwing an exception?" When an amd64 processor divides by zero, it sends an interrupt, which the operating system responds to by crashing the program. In order to get a user-readable exception in Mono, the runtime has to check the divisor before sending it to the CPU. This check takes time, and IL2CPP is (rightly or wrongly) not performing it. I think this could be said to be a bug in IL2CPP, since if the caller were catching DivideByZeroException, the program would have different control flow.

Comment: @TimC Thanks for all the insight, really helpful! :)